# Node.js FIFO - process hangs when writing to file descriptor

Tags: node.js, file, file-descriptor, fifo

I have the following Node.js code:

```
var fs=require('fs');
var util=require('util');

var n2c=fs.createReadStream('./n2c');
var c2n=fs.createReadStream('./c2n');

n2c.on('data', function(b){
        util.puts(b);
});
c2n.on('data',function(b){
        util.puts(b);
});
```

As you can see, I have two FIFO file descriptors (created using: `mkfifo n2c`, `mkfifo c2n`, `chmod 777 n2c c2n`)

When I do `echo "Hello" > n2c` in another window, "Hello" comes up fine. But when I try to do it again, `echo "Hello" > n2c` hangs and nothing comes up in the node.js window.

How do I fix this? I want to be able to echo "Hello" into the node.js window ad-infinitum.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that, when echo exits, the fifo will have hit the end of the 'file', so your readstream will emit the 'end' event and the read stream will close the file descriptor and no longer accept more data.

If you had two long-lived processes on either end if the fifo, then it wouldn't be an issue, but since echo writes and then closes, it stops the node stream quickly.

Your best option is probably to just re-create the stream whenever the current stream fires 'end'.

Not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for that insight. I think I'm going to use unix sockets instead for communicating between my Node.js program and my C program.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easy way to test your stream using the terminal:

```
$ cat > n2c
  Here you can type stuff
  that will be streamed whenever you add a
  newline.
  You can send EOF (end of file) by
  pressing Ctrl+D.
```

The stream will provide node with each line as you return, and won't cut off until you do Ctrl+D or otherwise send the EOF character.

The reason your `echo` dies after one line is because it automatically sends EOF after anything you type.

The answer is probably a bit late, but could be useful for others to know.